# How to build Jenkins quarkus native image?

Tags: jenkins, native, quarkus

I try to convert github action to jenkins pipeline. This github action generate a native image via Jib.

This is the commande line

```
mvn package -Pnative -DskipTests -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.registry=10.3.2.92:5000 -Dquarkus.container-image.push=true -Dquarkus.container-image.image=${SERVICE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME} '-Dquarkus.jib.labels."org.opencontainers.image.revision"='${TAG_NAME}
```

But i do not understant why it failed on jenkins.

Error raised is :

```
[2023-11-21T14:22:46.451Z] [ERROR]  [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.deployment.ContainerImageProcessor#publishImageInfo threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "registry" is null
```

I parse google with no success ..

If someone could help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

`quarkus.container-image.image` has to be full image reference, that's where your problem comes from.

### Why ?

As specified in documentation :

> `quarkus.container-image.image`
>
> Represents the entire image string. If set, then group, name, registry, tags, additionalTags are ignored

### So there are two solutions

#### Best one IMHO

Remove ignored fields and fix your `quarkus.container-image.image`, as it should be full url to your image, for example :

```
registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myimage:myversion
```

So in your case, it should look like this

```
10.3.2.92:5000/${SERVICE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
```

#### Or second one

As you provided `quarkus.container-image.image`, additional `quarkus.container-image.registry` is ignored. Simply remove `quarkus.container-image.image` and it should work as is.

### EDIT About private http only registry

As documentation state :

> The registry does not support HTTPS. We do not pass authentication details on non-HTTPS connections, though this can be overridden with the `sendCredentialsOverHttp` system property, but it is not recommend (version 0.9.9).

Simply add this param to your maven command :

```
-DsendCredentialsOverHttp=true
```

Comment: Nice :) Thanks @Jacouille. BTW, Jib cannot access to my private registry. Try to connect to https ://10.3.2.92:5000. Is still exist a solution to force it to access to http ?

Comment: @anthony44 I've updated my answer with informations regarding http only private registry. feel free to accept and upvote if it fulfilled your needs. Thanks !

Comment: quarkus.jib.jvm-arguments has no effect.. try to set quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments ?

Comment: yes you could try that, please tell me if this works better so I can update answer.
If not working, try setting directly `-DsendCredentialsOverHttp=true` with your maven command.

Comment: Thanks you so much @Jacouille ! please feel free to update your answer with this solution -DsendCredentialsOverHttp=true ... Merci !!!

Comment: I've updated, thanks for review ! ... Avec plaisir ;)